# jQuery to Ext conversion

Tags: jquery, extjs

What's the equivalent of `$('#id.class:input')` in `Ext`?
Or is there?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147192/how-to-use-jquery-something-to-select-a-class-in-extjs/2147905#2147905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Ext.query('#id.class:input')` but whether Ext's CSS selector engine is robust enough to handle that particular request, I'm not sure off the top of my head. Probably, it is. In any case, the [documentation](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext) says it returns an array of DOM elements that match your selector.

Edit: o.k.w. is right, too. `query` returns raw DOM elements, while `select` returns a `CompositeElement`, which is closer to the way jQuery does things.

Comment: I think Joel might be right too, after reading this: http://www.chnorton.com.au/2008/01/31/adventures-with-extjs-and-jquery/

Comment: Haha well, for jQuery guys, "query" seems to be more intuitive. +1

Comment: BTW,which of them has a longer history?

Comment: My guess is ExtJS first. But I wouldn't compare them directly.

Answer (score 4):

My guess based on this reference [Extjs quick start guide for jQuery Developers](http://ajaxray.com/blog/extjs-quick-start-guide-for-jquery-developers-javascript-howto)

```
// Select elements with CSS Selector
var elem = Ext.select("#id.class:input");

// or select directly from an existing element
var members = Ext.get('id');
var elem = members.select('input.class');
```