# How to use Jquery $(".something") to select a class in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I'm looking for an equivalent method to select a class element like this $(".className") in Jquery for ExtJS.

I understand that Ext.get() only takes in an id. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mickey

**Edited:**

Let me explain further. I want to be able to do something like Ext.get after I did a "select". For example:

```
$(".className").css("width");
```

I understand that Ext.Element has getWidth() method. I was hoping I can do something like...

```
Ext.select(".className").getWidth(); // it just return me [Object object]
```

Maybe i don't understand it well.

Thanks a mil.

Comment: Can you use Firebug? try to do console.dir(Ext.select(".className").getWidth()); and tell me what do you see in the console.

Comment: I see a list of functions and getWidth is inside the list.

Comment: When I did an alert, it returns [Object object]

Comment: Are there more elements with class=classname?

Comment: yes, there is more than one element with the same class.

Comment: Jquery is able to return it...

Comment: I don't know if Ext can do this. I'm not an expert on Ext but i try to edit my answer to give you piece of code that sould work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
Ext.query(".className");
```

This method allows you to get elements by the given query string like jQuery does.

**EDIT**

```
var els=Ext.query(".className"), ret=[];
for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
{
    ret.push(els[i].getWidth());
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope you can help me out. I want to be able to access Ext.Element methods (i.e. getWidth()). However, your suggested method of Ext.query return an array.

Comment: I see. I guess ExtJS can't be as elegant as Jquery with $(".className").css("width") to return the width. Thanks alot.

Comment: Ext.query is more useful when using DomQuery outside of Ext (hence, it returns a plain array).  If you want to operate on Element objects, use Ext.select.

Comment: Instead of the `for` loop it would be cleaner to use `ret = Ext.Array.map(els, function(item) { return item.getWidth(); });`.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [Ext.select()](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext&member=select) is what you want. It returns a [CompositeElement](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.CompositeElement) (same API as a single Element, but contains an internal collection of all selected elements).  You could do this to see the widths of each element:

```
Ext.select('.className').each(function(el){
    console.log(el.getWidth());
});
```

The way you called it is more useful for *operating* on the elements in some way, e.g.:

```
Ext.select('.className').setWidth(100);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the component you can use this:
**Ext4 and up.**

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[cls=myCls]');
```

And you will get and array of this components

source: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery