# is extjs have find() like jquery find() to search some doms

Tags: extjs

I start use extjs, I want find node like this

`Ext.get("addPersonForm").find('input')`

but  chorme tell me this

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'find'`

I want use extjs like jquery, jQuery use find is

`$("form").find("input")`

how can I use extjs like this

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147192/how-to-use-jquery-something-to-select-a-class-in-extjs?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at the API docs, instead of making up method names.

The methods that are probably interesting for your case, specifically, `query` would probably be the equivalent.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-child
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-down
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-method-query

`var items = Ext.get("addPersonForm").query('input');`

Comment: Don't wait marking this as answer. People with low ratings usually don't do this.

Comment: Not really sure I follow what you're saying.